# Change <li> order with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with many items and need to change the order. The idea is to have the items order by year. I like to archive this with JQuery or Javascript after the page is loaded.

```
<i>
    <ul data-option-key="filter" id="filter">
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a class="selected " title="All" data-option-value="*" href="#">All</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2015" data-option-value=".2015" href="#">2015</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2011" data-option-value=".2011" href="#">2011</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2006" data-option-value=".2006" href="#">2006</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2007" data-option-value=".2007" href="#">2007</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2008" data-option-value=".2008" href="#">2008</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2013" data-option-value=".2013" href="#">2013</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2010" data-option-value=".2010" href="#">2010</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2009" data-option-value=".2009" href="#">2009</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2014" data-option-value=".2014" href="#">2014</a>
        </li>
        <li class="milo-filter">
        <a title="2012" data-option-value=".2012" href="#">2012</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
</i>
```

Comment: Logic is the same as in the duplicate question, just change `$().data('position')` for `parseInt($().text(), 10)`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I added the script but it does not wotk out. Iam new to JS and Jquery so Iam not shure if i miss something to talk to the DOM. Also here you can see a life example: [link http://scoomadesign.com/pdi/index.php/portafolio ]   `code  <script>
  $(".milo-portfolio-pro li").sort(sort_li) // sort elements
                  .appendTo('.listitems'); // append again to the list
// sort function callback
function sort_li(a, b){
    return (parseInt($().text(), 10)) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;    
}                                     
    </script>`